# EF Core 2.2 with oracle DateTime.UtcNow

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a api in .net Core 3.0, EF Core 2.2 and a Oracle with database.
I know that is a bad practice queries linq like:

```
await db.Tickets.Where(t => t.x== x1 && t.DATE>
      DateTime.UtcNow).ToListAsync();
```

And the right form is like:

```
DateTime dateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow; 

await db.Tickets.Where(t => t.x==
      x1 && t.DATE> dateUtc ).ToListAsync();
```

But I don't know why EF translate the query like:

> SELECT table.x
> FROM table
> WHERE ((table.x = :locals1_PlateNumber_0) AND (table.DATE > SYSTIMESTAMP))

Why SYSTIMESTAMP instead SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(LOCALTIMESTAMP) (for example) ?

Somebody has the same problems?

Thanks a lot

**Update: the type of entity is a nullable datetime**